# MySQL insert into a table from multiple table filter by id

Tags: mysql

i'm try to insert into a table from multiple table.

here's my table

```
provinces table :
id , name 

regencies table :
id , province_id , name 

districts table :
id , regency_id , name

villages table :
id , district_id , name
```

i want to insert into a table with this structure :

```
tb_all
id , id_villages , villages_name , 
id_districts , districts_name , 
id_regency , regency_name , 
id_provinces , provinces_name
```

i'm really newbie about mysql command.

here's my query :

```
INSERT INTO tb_all (
    id_villages,
    villages_name,
    id_districts,
    districts_name,
    id_regency,
    regency_name,
    id_provinces,
    provinces_name)

    SELECT    v.id,
              v.name,
              d.id,
              d.name,
              r.id,
              r.name,
              p.id,
              p.name

    FROM villages AS v,
         districts AS d,
         regencies AS r,
         provinces AS p

    WHERE p.id = '73'
```

but i got this error :

```
**Error : Lock wait timeout exceeded**
```

i appreciate for any answer. thx.

Edit 2 :
another problem is when i run this query, my disk almost full :(

Comment: What's a mid_province?

Comment: mid_* column in a table with name all (table) for master ID provinces.

Comment: So mid = 'master id'? I suggest you post proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) together with a desired result.

Comment: i'm try to combine all this table into a single table and then execute some command to filter it by id, i'm really newbie with mysql programming mate...:(

Comment: I know. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: @Strawberry : what you suggest?

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tb_all` and post the result into your question.

Comment: Make your promary key (id_all) auto_increment.

Comment: @Paul : now i get this error :Error : Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (this local database)

Comment: @ZKE, please don't post long code in comments. Edit your question and post your code (properly formated) there.

Comment: really sorry, this is my 1st time using stackoverflow. i'll edit my question.

Comment: There is no reason to get a lock wait for this statement. There must be something else running and keeping a lock. Close your database engine and restart it to be absolutely sure nothing else is locking your tables. Secondly, your are doing a Cartesian product, so it you have 100 records in each of the 4 tables, you are generating 100000000 records!! Make sure this is what you really want.

Comment: i've try run SHOW PROCESSLIST before run this query, but there's nothing process run, restart mysql server and restart machine still nothing changes. i'm only need insert every provinces id = 73 not all.

Comment: @trincot : the reason i'm need to do this because villages table only show 3 column, i need to insert another column for provinces_name, regency_name, districts_name. total villages record only 81949 row and only 18.000 record sort by provinces_id=73  .

Comment: Your question has errors. The field names you list for *tb_all* are not same in the `insert` statement you wrote. There is *id_villages* and *mid_villages*, etc... Please check it all and correct please.

Comment: @trincot :oh sorry, i'm forgot to edit that part too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join your tables linking foreign keys to primary keys, otherwise you are generating a [Cartesian product](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3901221/Identifying-and-Eliminating-the-Dreaded-Cartesian-Product.htm), which will not be what you want, and may run your database engine to its limits.

As you wrote in comments, you do filter the *villages* records to 18,000 records. But you don't filter at all the other tables, of which *regencies* may have more than 5,000 records, *districts* 200, and *provinces* maybe 50. So you'd get the multiplication as the result set: 18,000 x 5,000 x 200 x 50 = 900 billion records!

Here is a suggested query. I suggest you first run the part that starts with `SELECT` to see if produces the correct records. Then when that is OK, run the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_all (
            id_villages,
            villages_name,
            id_districts,
            districts_name,
            id_regency,
            regency_name,
            id_provinces,
            provinces_name)
SELECT      v.id,
            v.name,
            d.id,
            d.name,
            r.id,
            r.name,
            p.id,
            p.name
FROM        provinces AS p
INNER JOIN  regencies AS r
        ON  r.province_id = p.id
INNER JOIN  districts AS d
        ON  d.regency_id = r.id
INNER JOIN  villages AS v
        ON  v.district_id = d.id
WHERE       p.id = 73
```

Comment: I got this error : Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version.

Comment: Did you add the table name after `INSERT INTO`? I just added that. Did you run the `SELECT` first, like I suggested? Did that work?

Comment: you're my hero... :) the problem with your query c.district_id change to v.district_id re-run query and everything works like a charm...ty

Comment: Great. Fixed the letter `c` like you wrote. (too small keyboard :) )

Comment: oh you should edit village AS v to villages AS v too and r.provinces_id = p.id into r.province_id = p.id too province,  once again, thank you very much ;)

Comment: Fixed, but please do the last correction in your question too, where you said the column name was `provinces_id`.